# Why does function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

So, I've recently started leaning how to code and I am trying to figure out how to create a function that will take a string and add the suffix 'ay' to the end if the conditions are met. For some reason, I keep getting 'undefined' whenever I run the function. I've tried rewriting it a few times but I keep getting something wrong and I can't figure out what it is! If someone can look this over and explain what I'm missing I would really appreciate it!

```
function translate(val) {
    let piggy = 'ay'
    let newVal = Array.from(val);
    let finalVal;
    let i = 0;
    while (i < newVal - 1) {
        if (newVal[0] == 'a' || newVal[0] == 'e' || newVal[0] == 'i' || newVal[0] == 'o' || newVal[0] == 'u') {
             finalVal = newVal.join('') + piggy;
             return finalVal;
        } else {
            finalVal = newVal;
            return finalVal;
        }
    i++
    } 
}
translate('apple')
```

Comment: What is `piggy` and where is it defined?

Comment: You're comparing a Number with an array, your program doesn't even go inside the while loop

Comment: @Derek.W, sorry just edited in! `piggy` is the suffix I want to add to the end of my string!

Comment: Yes, what ⵍⵢⴻⵙ said. Return a value after the while loop and you'll see that result.

Comment: `while (i < newVal - 1)` should be replaced to `while (i < newVal.length - 1)`.

Comment: @Derek.W Thank you that fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, you're subtracting a `number` from an array. This returns `NaN` and doesn't even hit the while loop. (`x < NaN` is always false)

Because you're not hitting the while loop the function just exists and never returns a value. That is why you receive `undefined`.

If you want to iterate over your newly created array, you'll want to use `newVal.length`.

Fixed code is as follows:

```
    let piggy = 'ay'
    let newVal = Array.from(val);
    let finalVal;
    let i = 0;
    while (i < newVal.length - 1) {
        if (newVal[0] == 'a' || newVal[0] == 'e' || newVal[0] == 'i' || newVal[0] == 'o' || newVal[0] == 'u') {
             finalVal = newVal.join('') + piggy;
             return finalVal;
        } else {
            finalVal = newVal;
            return finalVal;
        }
    i++
    } 
}
translate('apple')
```

Comment: I totally missed that! thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` statement, and I'm not sure what you are trying to do here... Are you trying to append `'ay'` to the string, if it starts with a vowel?

if yes, this is a simplified version of your code :

```
function translate( val ) {
  if([ "a", "e", "i","o","u"].includes(val[0])) {
     return val + 'ay';
     }
   else return val;
}
```

Comment: basically i'm trying to write a function that will take a word and translate it to pig latin but that's beyond my scope of knowledge atm. thank you btw!!